# Set /a missing operand

Tags: batch-file

I have tried everything on this site for this issue and it is still not working even when I remove the percent signs it doesn't do the math. Here's the code

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (Bought.txt) do (
    echo Newly bought shares %%b
    set c=0.001
    set /a a=b*c
    echo Next tick's price change: %a%
)
```

with the percent signs it outputs

```
Missing operand.
```

without the signs

```
Next tick's price change: 0
```

and keep in mind that even with the "b" variable set to anything it still outputs zero.

Comment: This is IMO the most recurring question about delayed expansion. Second is set /a only deals with integers no floats. So c is zero  and a also.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment already stated this won't be what you expected
(and you forgot to use %%b instead of only b):

```
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (Bought.txt) do (
    echo Newly bought shares %%b
    set c=0.001
    set /a a=%%b*!c!
    echo Next tick's price change: !a!
)
```

**EDIT** To divide through thousand (with simulated floating point math) use:

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (Bought.txt) do (
    echo Newly bought shares %%b
    set c=1000
    set /a a=%%b / c, d = (%%b %% c ^)
    Set d=000!d!
    echo Next tick's price change: !a!.!d:~-3!
)
```

Thanks for the hint JosefZ

Comment: `set /a a=%%b / c` works as well instead of `set /a a=%%b / !c!`

Comment: Does everything great, thank you I knew it probably had something to do with the EnableDelayedExpansion